# React: Couldn't find preset "env react" relative to directory "src"

Tags: reactjs, babel-preset-env

I have added presets react and env into my react project using the command below:

yarn global  add babel-preset-react@6.24.1 babel-preset-env@1.5.2

```
My package.json file has updated the presets and looks like the following:
  {
  "name": "indecesion-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "ak",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-env": "1.5.2",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.24.1"
  }
}
```

Even my node_modules folder has updated the presets.

The folder structure looks like this:

indecesion-app(folder name of the app)

- node_modules
- public
- src
- package.json
- yarn.lock

  Now when I run the command

indecesion-app> babel src/app.js --out-file=public/scripts/app.js --presets=env,react

It is showing the error:

```
Error: Couldn't find preset "env react" relative to directory "src"
at C:\Users\anil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\babel-cli\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:293:19
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at OptionManager.resolvePresets (C:\Users\anil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\babel-cli\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:275:20)
at OptionManager.mergePresets (C:\Users\anil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\babel-cli\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:264:10)
at OptionManager.mergeOptions (C:\Users\anil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\babel-cli\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:249:14)
at OptionManager.init (C:\Users\anil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\babel-cli\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:368:12)
at File.initOptions (C:\Users\anil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\babel-cli\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:212:65)
at new File (C:\Users\anil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\babel-cli\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:135:24)
at Pipeline.transform (C:\Users\anil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\babel-cli\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\pipeline.js:46:16)
at transform (C:\Users\anil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\babel-cli\lib\babel\util.js:50:22)
```

Please suggest a solution

Comment: Shouldn't you install [@babel/preset-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/preset-react) instead of `babel-preset-react` ?
The second one is way older, and the first one is explained on the [babel website](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-react) directly.

Same remark on `babel-preset-env` with 
 [@babel/preset-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/preset-env)

Comment: @Orlyyn   I tried @babel/preset-react and env, but getting the same error.

Answer (score 22):

I had the same problem and was able to fix it just by adding quotes:

babel src/app.js --out-file=public/scripts/app.js --presets="env,react"

Comment: I've just had this same error and this solution helped me. Adding quotes here: `--presets="env,react"`

Answer (score 4):

**First of all, be sure to have installed the following packages:**

npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/cli @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react

**Then run the following command:**

babel src/app.js --out-file=public/scripts/app.js --presets="env,react"

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem as this looks like it is part of the Udemy course on React.

1. Delete all of your global NPM/Yarn modules related to Babel. On Windows mine were in c:\users\user\appdata\roaming\npm\nodemodules as it was installed globally.
2. npm init the project
3. npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/cli
4. npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-react @babel/preset-env
5. npx babel .\src\app.js -o .\public\scripts\app.js --presets=@babel/preset-env,@babel/preset-react

Answer (score 2):

Here's what worked for me.  Delete any Babel in the node_modules directory.  Then, the first 3 steps as motoXORx90 stated..

npm init the project

npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/cli

npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-react @babel/preset-env

For the last step do:

npx babel src/app.js --out-file=public/scripts/app.js --presets=@babel/preset-env,@babel/preset-react

Answer (score 1):

just use the code

```
babel src/app.js --out-file=public/scripts/app.js --presets='env,react'
```

Answer (score 1):

For all those guys out there, who are working on react course of UDEMY and facing this error, a simple fix available here. **Don't uninstall anything... just execute the below statement**

babel src/app.js --out-file=public/scripts/app.js --presets='env,react'

**That's it**

Thank me later.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, be sure to have installed the following packages:

```sh
npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/cli @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react
```

Assuming that you installed the packages above, in the [babel docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-cli), it states that to use preset, you should do the following:

```sh
--presets=@babel/preset-react,@babel/preset-env
```

So your babel command should look like this:

```sh
babel src/app.js --out-file=public/scripts/app.js --presets=@babel/preset-react,@babel/preset-env
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: HI Orlynn, the same issue persists even after applying your command.

Comment: For this command, I used the `@babel/cli` package, and called it with `npx babel` instead of just `babel`... I encountered your problem on the --presets values, and solved it by using the different @babel/ packages... Maybe try with the [@babel/cli](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-cli) package as well ?

Comment: I deleted bable and reinstalled it globally using npm i -g  @babel/cli. I then commanded: yarn init, in my root folder which generated package.json file. Then: yarn  add @babel/preset-react @babel/preset-env. now dependencies of presets were added in package.json. Then I did  babel src/app.js --out-file=public/scripts/app.js --presets=@babel/preset-react,@babel/preset-env. Now a new error is coming which says "Cannot find module '@babel/core'  ". I just pasted a small portion of the error log

Answer (score 0):

I followed above answers but still couldn't make it run. Then I noticed what is written in error logs. Followed their advice and following command ran perfectly

```
npx babel .\src\app.js -o .\public\scripts\app.js --presets=module:@babel\preset-env,module:@babel\preset-react
```

My package.json

```
"@babel/cli": "^7.10.5",
"@babel/core": "^7.11.1",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.0",
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.4"
```

Answer (score 0):

In your command you forgot to  put the **""(double quotes)** as you defined the presets correct is

```
 --presets="env,react"
```

not

```
--presets=env,react  //wrong
```

so just add the double quotes so the correct command is .

```
babel src/app.js --out-file=public/scripts/app.js --presets="env,react"
```